# How to convert shape file to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr?

Tags: gis, geojson, gdal, shapefile

I'm trying to generate MBTiles file using [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) and to do that first I am converting a shape file downloaded from Geofabric downloads to a GeoJSON file using ogr2ogr and then using that GeoJSON file to MBTiles file using tippecanoe.

The step I'm stuck on is this

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON turk.geojson turkmenistan-latest-free.shp
```

The file which I downloaded from Geofabric is a `.shp.zip` file - https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/turkmenistan-latest-free.shp.zip. On extracting this zip file I get a folder which contains various files like `gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.cpg` etc. However, there was no `turkmenistan-latest-free.shp` file - or one .shp file which contained all of Turkmenistan.

When I run `ogr2ogr` command directly on the folder which was extracted out of the .zip file, I get this error

```
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1 (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

If I run the same command with `-skipfailures`, I get more errors

```
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_natural_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_natural_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_places_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_places_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_pofw_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_pofw_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_pois_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_pois_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_railways_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_roads_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_traffic_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_traffic_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_transport_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_transport_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_water_a_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Layer 'gis_osm_waterways_free_1' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
```

However, on inspecting the folder all these files already exist in it, but ogr2ogr is somehow unable to find it. These are the files in the folder

```
README                          gis_osm_natural_free_1.shp   gis_osm_pofw_free_1.prj      gis_osm_roads_free_1.dbf        gis_osm_transport_free_1.cpg
gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.cpg  gis_osm_natural_free_1.shx   gis_osm_pofw_free_1.shp      gis_osm_roads_free_1.prj        gis_osm_transport_free_1.dbf
gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.dbf  gis_osm_places_a_free_1.cpg  gis_osm_pofw_free_1.shx      gis_osm_roads_free_1.shp        gis_osm_transport_free_1.prj
gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.prj  gis_osm_places_a_free_1.dbf  gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.cpg    gis_osm_roads_free_1.shx        gis_osm_transport_free_1.shp
gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.shp  gis_osm_places_a_free_1.prj  gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.dbf    gis_osm_traffic_a_free_1.cpg    gis_osm_transport_free_1.shx
gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.shx  gis_osm_places_a_free_1.shp  gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.prj    gis_osm_traffic_a_free_1.dbf    gis_osm_water_a_free_1.cpg
gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.cpg    gis_osm_places_a_free_1.shx  gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.shp    gis_osm_traffic_a_free_1.prj    gis_osm_water_a_free_1.dbf
gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.dbf    gis_osm_places_free_1.cpg    gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.shx    gis_osm_traffic_a_free_1.shp    gis_osm_water_a_free_1.prj
gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.prj    gis_osm_places_free_1.dbf    gis_osm_pois_free_1.cpg      gis_osm_traffic_a_free_1.shx    gis_osm_water_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.shp    gis_osm_places_free_1.prj    gis_osm_pois_free_1.dbf      gis_osm_traffic_free_1.cpg      gis_osm_water_a_free_1.shx
gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.shx    gis_osm_places_free_1.shp    gis_osm_pois_free_1.prj      gis_osm_traffic_free_1.dbf      gis_osm_waterways_free_1.cpg
gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.cpg    gis_osm_places_free_1.shx    gis_osm_pois_free_1.shp      gis_osm_traffic_free_1.prj      gis_osm_waterways_free_1.dbf
gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.dbf    gis_osm_pofw_a_free_1.cpg    gis_osm_pois_free_1.shx      gis_osm_traffic_free_1.shp      gis_osm_waterways_free_1.prj
gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.prj    gis_osm_pofw_a_free_1.dbf    gis_osm_railways_free_1.cpg  gis_osm_traffic_free_1.shx      gis_osm_waterways_free_1.shp
gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.shp    gis_osm_pofw_a_free_1.prj    gis_osm_railways_free_1.dbf  gis_osm_transport_a_free_1.cpg  gis_osm_waterways_free_1.shx
gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.shx    gis_osm_pofw_a_free_1.shp    gis_osm_railways_free_1.prj  gis_osm_transport_a_free_1.dbf
gis_osm_natural_free_1.cpg      gis_osm_pofw_a_free_1.shx    gis_osm_railways_free_1.shp  gis_osm_transport_a_free_1.prj
gis_osm_natural_free_1.dbf      gis_osm_pofw_free_1.cpg      gis_osm_railways_free_1.shx  gis_osm_transport_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_natural_free_1.prj      gis_osm_pofw_free_1.dbf      gis_osm_roads_free_1.cpg     gis_osm_transport_a_free_1.shx
```

What am I doing incorrectly here and how can I properly generate the GeoJSON file?

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no `turkmenistan-latest-free.shp` shape file, so you can't convert it to GeoJSON.

You can convert either of the shapefiles in your directory:

```
gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_landuse_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_natural_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_natural_free_1.shp
gis_osm_places_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_places_free_1.shp
gis_osm_pofw_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_pofw_free_1.shp
gis_osm_pois_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_pois_free_1.shp
gis_osm_railways_free_1.shp
gis_osm_roads_free_1.shp
gis_osm_traffic_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_traffic_free_1.shp
gis_osm_transport_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_transport_free_1.shp
gis_osm_water_a_free_1.shp
gis_osm_waterways_free_1.shp
```

by just running

`ogr2ogr output.json input.shp`

like for example:

`ogr2ogr gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.json gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.shp`

You can check if the files (input or output) are valid with `ogrinfo`:

```sh
ogrinfo gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.json

# INFO: Open of `gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1.json'
#       using driver `GeoJSON' successful.
# 1: gis_osm_buildings_a_free_1
```